# I am trying to add a trend line to this plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have this graph:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
1.230448921,0.460822919
1.342422681,0.694747354
1.431363764,0.828862164
1.505149978,0.993514561
1.568201724,1.257457266
1.62324929,1.521115401
1.672097858,1.822516751
1.716003344,2.125021632
1.755874856,2.355223203
1.792391689,2.567059417
1.826074803,2.763380773
1.857332496,2.932403886
1.886490725,3.081848588
1.913813852,3.208627804
1.939519253,3.324555792
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
a,b
1.230448921,0.460822919
1.230448921,0.694747354
1.342422681,0.694747354
1.342422681,0.828862164
1.431363764,0.828862164
1.431363764,0.993514561
1.505149978,0.993514561
1.505149978,1.257457266
1.568201724,1.257457266
1.568201724,1.521115401
1.62324929,1.521115401
1.62324929,1.822516751
1.672097858,1.822516751
1.672097858,2.125021632
1.716003344,2.125021632
1.716003344,2.355223203
1.755874856,2.355223203
1.755874856,2.567059417
1.792391689,2.567059417
1.792391689,2.763380773
1.826074803,2.763380773
1.826074803,2.932403886
1.857332496,2.932403886
1.857332496,3.081848588
1.886490725,3.081848588
1.886490725,3.208627804
1.913813852,3.208627804
1.913813852,3.324555792
1.939519253,3.324555792
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    title = log-log,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[blue] table [x=a,y=b,col sep=comma] {test.csv};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That gives the following graph:

[image]

I would like to add a trend line in red from the data in `data.csv` and display the equation. I am new to latex.  In `test.csv`, I simply modified the coordinates to have the steps; is there a more elegant way of plotting points as series of steps? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Load `pgfplotstable` (which loads `pgfplots` too) and read the `test.csv` as, say, `\datatable`. Then you can add

```
\addplot[red] table[
    y={create col/linear regression={y=b}}
]{\datatable};
```

to plot the trend line.  The slope and intercept of the trend line are stored in `\pgfplotstableregressiona` and `\pgfplotstableregressionb` respectively. You can add a legend for the trendline forming an equation like

```
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
a,b
1.230448921,0.460822919
1.230448921,0.694747354
1.342422681,0.694747354
1.342422681,0.828862164
1.431363764,0.828862164
1.431363764,0.993514561
1.505149978,0.993514561
1.505149978,1.257457266
1.568201724,1.257457266
1.568201724,1.521115401
1.62324929,1.521115401
1.62324929,1.822516751
1.672097858,1.822516751
1.672097858,2.125021632
1.716003344,2.125021632
1.716003344,2.355223203
1.755874856,2.355223203
1.755874856,2.567059417
1.792391689,2.567059417
1.792391689,2.763380773
1.826074803,2.763380773
1.826074803,2.932403886
1.857332496,2.932403886
1.857332496,3.081848588
1.886490725,3.081848588
1.886490725,3.208627804
1.913813852,3.208627804
1.913813852,3.324555792
1.939519253,3.324555792
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{test.csv}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    title = log-log,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[blue] table [x=a,y=b,col sep=comma] {\datatable};
\addplot[red] table[
    y={create col/linear regression={y=b}}
]
{\datatable};
\addlegendentry{Data}
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there also a way to get the equation?

Comment: @Johnathan Please see the edit.

Comment: @Johnathan: We appreciate one question per post in this site. It is better to ask a new question IMO, if you mean "...elegant way of plotting points as series of steps"

Comment: Thank you! Ok. So it's ok to post two different questions with the some code? I am new to latex, and would greatly appreciate if you could please explain:
1) Is \datatable a variable or a pointer that represents the file? It seems like it.
2) I've seen the % and $ before but don't understand them. Does the $ encapsulate a statement to be evaluated? What about %?
Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: @Johnathan It is ok as long as the questions are diffrent. `\datatable` represents the data in the file it is reading, for example `test.csv` here. Change the file and data changes. Please read `pgfplotstable` manual.